# I have an XMOS 7-mic board using the CS43L21 for DAC output. I get it working at 48 kHz, but not at 8 kHz, following the example of XMOS AN00219

Tags: headphones

What I am looking for is some open driver that tackles more than just 48 kHz.

Or a trick, if there is one.

PIN30 MCLK gets 24.576 MHz and I have internal counters to count down with, for the speed of the I2S.

Comment: Sample rate supported by each input interface:
PCM:44.1KHz,48KHz,88.2KHz,96KHz,176.4KHz,
192KHz,352.8KHz,384KHz

Comment: Thanks! As far as I can see in the CS43L21 data sheet there are "sample rate (LRCK)" of 8 to 96 kHz in steps. But this is dependent on MCLK, which on this board is 24576000 Hz from a PLL that may be controlled, though. You indicate some higher steps. It would be great to have this seen in perspective. The circuit diagram is at https://www.xmos.ai/download/xCORE-Microphone-Array-hardware-manual(2V0).pdf

Comment: Sorry for the error in the heading! I'm talking about DAC all the time here, not ADC. I got the letters confused, I must admit.

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the datasheet, the CS43L21 does not automatically support 8 kHz sampling rate with 24.576 MHz MCLK.

Either halve the MCLK output from the PLL, or enable MCLK dividing by 2 at the DAC in hardware or software, or disable auto-detection and set the MCLK to FS ratio manually.

Comment: Thanks! I think I have done what you state, but I'll fine read your comments and then come back here. Øyvind

Comment: Thanks, @Justme. I do think that should be in place. But in trying to understand what XMOS might have done, and what I have done, I have made a description of it all (PDF), and made my code available. This is just a hobby project with one of the purposes to be shared, with no ads or income from my notes. It's at [link](https://www.teigfam.net/oyvind/home/technology/219-my-beep-brrr-notes/#mclk_dac_and_pdm_mics_sw)